# Fibrations of curves whose singular locus on the base is not codimension $1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f : X \to B$ a relative curve meaning a flat proper map whose fibers are geometrically connected $1$-dimensional schemes. In what follows,let $B$ be a smooth variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ be generically smooth.

When $f$ is at worst nodal, there is a divisor on the base over which $f$ is singular. This can be shown from the deformation theory of a node and the versal space $\mathrm{Spec}(k[t][x,y]/(xy - t)) \to \mathrm{Spec}(k[t])$.

For other hypersurface singularities, I think one can make a similar argument to show there is a divisor over which $f$ is not smooth.

Are there examples (with worse singularities) where the singular locus on the base is not pure codimension $1$?

Comment: There are elementary examples when you drop the "connectedness" hypothesis, e.g., the "main component" of the Hilbert scheme in $\mathbb{P}^4$ with Hilbert polynomial $2t+2$, i.e., the parameter space of unions of two (not necessarily intersecting) lines.  If you drop the flatness hypothesis, but retain that the morphism should be a proper, surjective morphism between quasiprojective normal varieties with irreducible, $1$-dimensional fibers, there are also examples coming from degree-$2$, genus-$0$ stable maps to $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: Thank you @JasonStarr for the examples. Without dropping my hypotheses do you think there are examples?

Comment: I believe that there are examples: perhaps already the Hilbert scheme in $\mathbb{P}^n$ for the Hilbert polynomial $et+1$ (i.e., degree-$e$ smooth rational curves, among others).  I will try to check the details and write more.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example. Let
$$
X = C(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2) \subset \mathbb{P}^6
$$
be the cone over the Segre embedding. Then for general $\Pi_0 = \mathbb{P}^3 \subset \mathbb{P}^6$ the intersection
$$
Z := X \cap \Pi_0
$$
is a smooth twisted cubic curve. Now consider the 2-dimensional space of all $\Pi = \mathbb{P}^4 \subset \mathbb{P}^6$ containing $\Pi_0$ and let
$$
X_\Pi := X \cap \Pi.
$$
If $\Pi$ does not contain the vertex of $X$ then $X_\Pi$ is a hyperplane section of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2$ containing $Z$, hence it is a smooth cubic scroll, and if $\Pi$ contains the vertex, then $X_\Pi$ is a cone over $Z$. Since the latter happens for the unique $\Pi$ in the above 2-dimensional space, this gives a required example.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but isn't the family of $X_{\Pi}$ a relative *surface* over a $2$-dimensional base parametrizing $\Pi$.

Comment: Did you want a curve? Sorry, I missed this requirement.